# Syntax/Unicode errors with a Windows Path

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code :

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from getpass import getpass

username = input("Enter your user name :")
password = getpass("Enter your password : ")
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Users\Ashok\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://github.com/login")

username_textbox = driver.find_element_by_id("login_field")
username_textbox.send_keys(username)

password_textbox = driver.find_element_by_id("password")
password_textbox.send_keys(password)

signiin_button = driver.find_element_by_name("commit")
signiin_button .submit()
```

The error that I am getting :

```
python Voiceassistance.py
  File "Voiceassistance.py", line 6
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Users\Ashok\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
                              ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Replace your line with

   `driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\Ashok\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe')`

   Since `\` is used for escaping special characters, you invalidly escaped `U` and other characters and it will cause an error.
2. Another method is replace `\` with `/`

   `driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/Ashok/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')`
3. You can also add a flag `r` for raw string

   `driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\Ashok\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')`